The links to TL in the mod messages tab are broken
I noticed this on Economics.SE but from other moderators I hear they are having similar problems so it seems it is site wide issue.
The link in the mod messages tab is; https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/message/chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4
but the correct link should be (or at least the one that works is); https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge

Screenshots (from CR.SE):
When attempting to send a moderator message (on https://<site>.stackexchange.com/users/message/create/<id>), the words "Teachers' Lounge" contain a broken link in the bottom right of the "What is a moderator message?" section:



Could you link to the page on Economics (the mod message tab's page) that has that link (so long as the link has no info we shouldn't know about)? It'll 404 for us mortals but staff will be able to confirm.

@Spevacus hmm let me try, the convo I have open should be private according to moderator agreement but let me try to open message tab on my own account

@Spevacus I cant get it to work because I cannot reply to my own mod test message and without reply it does not show

No worries. If the workflow is straightforward (I don't know how it works, not a moderator) then anyone familiar should be able to see the problem.

yes basically, when you reply to reply of a user to your mod message then another text 'drops' on right down corner titled "What is a moderator message?" which contains some explanations and then links one of them is to TL which is broken
